# Apicurio registry - Documentation tab for artifact is empty

Tags: api, registry, redhat

When I upload artifact to the ApiCurio registry using UI it works fine but if I use CURL for the same artifact, Documentation tab is empty. Any ideas?

I use:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-Registry-ArtifactType: OPENAPI" -H "X-Registry-ArtifactId: test"    --data "{$body}" http://registry:8080/api/artifacts
```

Answer (score 0):

should use "$body" instead of "{$body}"